# Yii insert record instead of update

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii framework but this is probably regarding my php code.

I have 3 methods in my controller,   1 for creating, 1 for updating, 1 for saving.
creating and updating render the same form.

Everything works fine for saving the record.  But when I updated a record, it creates a new record.
In my update method,  I load the existing record and I get the correct value, but when I save it saves it in a new record. I'm try with $model->update()  instead of $model->save(), but I got the error that I cannot update a new record.

Thank in advance for any insights

**method create**

```
$model = new Comment;

        $this->renderPartial('_formComment',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'post_id'=>$post_id,)
        );
```

**method update**

```
$model=$this->loadModel($comment_id);

        $this->renderPartial('_formComment',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'post_id'=>$model->post_id,
                'comment_id'=>$model->id,)
        );
```

**method to save**

```
$comment=new Comment;

if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];

        if($model->save()) {

            echo ('save ok');                   

        }
    }
```

**my loadmodel function called by my update method**

```
if($this->_model===null)
        {

            $this->_model=Comment::model()->findbyPk($comment_id);
            if($this->_model===null)
                throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        }
        return $this->_model;
```

Comment: Educated guess: your form submits a blank value for the primary key attribute, and your model does not have a validation rule to skip it.

Comment: @DCoder  Yes, you are right.  I thought that simply doing $model->attributes=$_POST['Opinion'];  will set the comment_id to the current value of the comment primary key.  But when I set $model->id to the current comment id,  I got the integrity error, it tries to insert a record with the same primary key.
I tried with update instead of save and it still the same.  Trying to update a new record.

Comment: Your "method to save" doesn't look right, because you're mixing `$comment` and `$model`. You should be loading an existing comment by its ID, not doing `new Comment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
$comment=new Comment;
```

in save method, it always create a new model. But you need load existing model, set attributes and save it. Pass $model in save method.

Comment: ok,  thank you.  I changed my save method and check the id, in case the of existing id , I dont create new Comment.  @alexk984